# OAuth login not returning to redirect uri

Tags: authentication, oauth

I have configured our salesforce sandbox as an OIDC provider in an AWS Cognito user pool.  Sometimes when logging in this way, the user is redirected to salesforce after logging in rather than back to the Cognito redirect uri.

I have narrowed this down to being related to the size of the "state" parameter that AWS Cognito passes to salesforce.

Cognito redirects to:

> https://(sandbox hostname).force.com/(partner
> site)/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=(client
> id)&redirect_uri=(redirect
> uri)&scope=openid&response_type=code&state=(encoded data)

This in turn redirects to:

> https://(sandbox hostname).force.com/(partner
> site)/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=(encoded
> data)

At this point, the flow can go one of two ways.

When the "state" value from Cognito is small, this request results in an html page which does a GET request to

> https://(sandbox hostname).force.com/(partner
> site)/s/login?ec=(number)&inst=(number)&startURL=(encoded data)

When this happens the login page is displayed and the user is redirected to Cognito's redirect uri and everything works fine.

When the "state" value is large (greater than about 1000 characters) the html page returned by the apexp request does a POST to the same login url, including the "ec", "inst" and "startURL" in the request body.  When this hpapens, the use is redirected to

> https://(sandbox hostname).force.com/(partner site)/s/

after logging in, which should never happen.

My theory is that the GET/POST difference exists because some browsers have a url length limit of about 2k characters, which would cause the GET version to fail.  However RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp is not accounting for this.

Comment: Update: This appears to be due to the partner site using a custom "Experience Builder Page" as the login page.

Comment: do you have a documentation that you followed?